# Reals and collapsing posets

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $M$ be a ctm of $ZFC$, and let $P$ be the poset $\prod_{n<\omega}^{\text{fin}} \text{Coll}(\omega,\aleph_n)$ as computed within $M$.

Let $G$ be $P$-generic over $M$. Let $G^{<n}\times G^{\ge n}$ be the image of $G$ under the natural isomorphism $P\cong P^{<n}\times P^{\ge n}$

Let $X=\bigcup_{n<\omega} \mathcal{P}(\omega)\cap M[G^{< n}]$.

I'd like to show that $X\neq \mathcal{P}(\omega)\cap M[G]$, i.e. there is some subset of $\omega$ in the big generic extension which is not added in any of the smaller ones. I'm puzzled because this forcing adds surjections $\omega\to\aleph_n^M$, so I don't know how to get reals into the mix.

Any hints on how to get started?

Comment: Recall that there is a surjection from $\mathcal P(\omega)$ onto $\omega_1$ given by coding of countable ordinals. If you collapse $\aleph_1$, you have to have added reals because we have more countable ordinals, and therefore more well-orders to code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you really shouldn't be puzzled about how you can get reals!  Reals are really easy to build from other data.  For instance, given a map $\omega\to\omega_n^M$, you can get a real by composing it with any map $\omega_n^M\to 2$.  Basically, the thing to keep in mind is that $M[G]$ doesn't just have $G$ added--it also has lots of other sets which can be "built" from $G$ or which encode the data of $G$ in different ways.  A real is just a countable sequence of yes/no choices, and such countable sequences can be encoded inside other objects in tons of ways.

Now, you want a real that is not in $M[G^{<n}]$ for any $n$.  Intuitively, this means the real cannot be constructed from finitely many of the surjections $\omega\to\omega_n^M$ which $G$ gives you, but instead can only be constructed if you really have all of them (or at least infinitely many of them).  So, how could you define a real that uses data from all of the surjections $\omega\to\omega_n^M$ at once?

Comment: What I came up with: Since $\mathbb{P}^{\lt n}$ has the $\aleph_n \text{-c.c.}$, $\aleph_n$ is a cardinal in $M[G^{\lt n}]$ and we add reals when passing from $M[G^{\lt n}]$ to $M[G^{\lt n+1}]$ because we collapse it. So let $g_n:\omega \rightarrow 2$ be such a real for each $n$. Now let $g: \omega^2 \rightarrow 2$ be s.t. $g(n, m) = g_n(m)$ and let $h:\omega \rightarrow \omega^2$ be the inverse of the pairing function. $goh$ is the desired real. Since if it falls in any of the $M[G^{\lt n}]$ all the information can be decoded. This is correct right? Also how can one use the surjections?

Comment: That works.  You can do something much more direct, though.  For instance, if $f_n:\omega\to\omega_n^M$ is the surjection given by $G$, you could define $f:\omega\to 2$ by just letting $f(n)$ be determined by $f_n$ in some simple way.  (For instance, $f(n)$ could be $0$ if $f_n(0)<f_n(1)$ and $1$ otherwise.)

Comment: I thought about some functions similar to the one you mentioned but I can't see why they can't appear in $M[G^{\lt n}]$ for example.

Comment: You can use the fact that $G^{\geq n}$ is generic over $M[G^{<n}]$.  Show that for any real $g$ in $M[G^{<n}]$, the set of conditions in $P^{\geq n}$ that force $f$ to be different from $g$ is dense.